# How to make gdal_translate support MrSID driver

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, mrsid

I am using `gdal_translate -b ... in.sid out.sid` to remove excess bands (there are 5 bands) from .sid files as a layer created from these .sid's will be a JPEG layer. When executing command on a .sid file and expecting to get .sid file as an ouput but I get a .tiff and a warning

```
Warning: The target file has a 'sid' extension, which is normally used by the MrSID driver,
but the requested output driver is GTiff
```

"The following format drivers are configured and support output" list does not show MrSID driver among supported drivers.

**How to make gdal_translate support MrSID driver?**

Comment: MrSID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MrSID is licensed, by LizardTech last time I looked, but links go to extensis https://www.extensis.com/, you could purchase a license to compress but from experience that still wont help GDAL_Translate - you have to use their compressor utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html ("no" in both Creation and Copy columns) and in https://www.gdal.org/frmt_mrsid.html the driver is read-only.

> This driver supports reading of MrSID image files using Extensis'
>   decoding software development kit (DSDK).

Use some of the drivers which support writing. GeoTIFF is not a bad choise. It is also a good practise to define the desired output driver explicitly with -of parameter even GDAL makes some guessing by the filename extension.